# Is "if you fought yourself" correct?

Tags: grammar

I just messaged a friend the sentence:

> If you fought yourself, who would win?

But it sounds awkward to me.

This sounds more correct to me:

> If you were to fight yourself, who would win?

Grammatically, which is correct?

Comment: They both sound fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

The backshift to **fought** and the subjunctive **were** are both ways of indicating that the sentence is not a declaration of fact but a hypothetical or conditional.

Compare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppose_They_Gave_a_War_and_Nobody_Came

Comment: What does "backshift" mean?

Comment: "Backshift" refers to the use of the past tense of the verb instead of the present, or the use of the past perfect instead of the past, in situations where the clause is not asserting a present fact or a past fact but is stating something that is now (or was then) hypothetical, conjectural, suppositional, a wish, reported speech, and so forth